# Is there a way to refer back to default in a swich case?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am making a tick tack toe cli game that takes user imput and prints an updated board. One of the features i want it to have is that it can recognise that there already is a character in the slot that you want to put your piece.
right now i have a switch case with the default not changing anything. can i refer back to it or if i should just copy paste it into each case.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TickTack {
    String[][] tickTackToe =
                        {{" ","|"," ","|"," "},
                        {"-","-","-","-","-"},
                        {" ","|"," ","|"," "},
                        {"-","-","-","-","-"},
                        {" ","|"," ","|"," "}};

    int xCoor = 0, yCoor = 0, counter = 1;

    //ignore this they do not matter yet
    int rOne = 0,rTwo = 0, rThree = 0;
    int cOne = 0, cTwo = 0, cThree = 0;
    int dOne = 0, dTwo = 0;
    String x = "";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);



    public void play() {
        while (!x.equals("win")){
            for (int fila = 0; fila < 5; fila++) {
                for (int columna = 0; columna < 5; columna++) {
                    System.out.print(tickTackToe[fila][columna]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            boolean checker = false;
            while (!checker) {
                x = in.next();
                switch (x) {
                    //first row
                    case "1,1" -> {
                        xCoor = 0;
                        yCoor = 0;
                        checker = true;
                    }
                    case "1,2" -> {
                        xCoor = 0;
                        yCoor = 2;
                        checker = true;
                    }
                     case "1,3" -> {
                        xCoor = 0;
                        yCoor = 4;
                        checker = true;
                    }
                    //second row
                    case "2,1" -> {
                        xCoor = 2;
                        yCoor = 0;
                        checker = true;
                    }
                    case "2,2" -> {
                        xCoor = 2;
                        yCoor = 2;
                        checker = true;
                    }
                    case "2,3" -> {
                        xCoor = 2;
                        yCoor = 4;
                        checker = true;
                    }
                    //third row
                    case "3,1" -> {
                        xCoor = 4;
                        yCoor = 0;
                        checker = true;
                    }
                    case "3,2" -> {
                        xCoor = 4;
                        yCoor = 2;
                        checker = true;
                    }
                    case "3,3" -> {
                        xCoor = 4;
                        yCoor = 4;
                        checker = true;
                    }
                    default -> System.out.println("that is not a valid option");
                }
            }

            //check whose turn is it and alocate the piece
            counter ++;
            if (counter % 2 == 0){
                tickTackToe[yCoor][xCoor] = "x";
            }else{
                tickTackToe[yCoor][xCoor] = "o";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i looked at a bunch of switch statement tutorials(w3 schools, geeks for geeks, javapoint)
but i didnt find anything

Comment: I couldn't understand your question.

Comment: I  general you should not cut and paste.  When you find common code, factor it out into its own method. But your switch statement is not a good way to do what you are doing in any case.

Comment: i ended up copy pasting my code.
though it generaly bad practice creating a function and calling it would just be creating more code.

swpalmer you said that there is a better way to do this, can you please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot revert back to default - and you do not have to.

If inside a case you detect that the field is already used, just print a message `field already occupied`, then use `break` to end the case. It is different from the user issuing an unforeseen command where your default case will print `that is not a valid option`. And therefore no cut&paste.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad idea:

```
switch (x) {
//first row
case "1,1" -> {
  xCoor = 0;
  yCoor = 0;
    checker = true;
}
case "1,2" -> {
  xCoor = 0;
  yCoor = 2;
  checker = true;
}...
```

You shouldn't be using a switch statement at all here.
Try something like this:

```
boolean checker = false;
while (!checker) {
  x = in.next().trim();
  String [] parts = x.split(",");
  try {
    xCoor = (Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) - 1) * 2;
    yCoor = (Integer.parseInt(parts[1]) - 1) * 2;
    checked = (xCoor >= 0 && xCoor <= 4
            && yCoor >= 0 && yCoor <= 4
            && tickTackToe[yCoor][xCoor].equals(" "));
  } catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException | NumberFormatException ex) {
    // fall through with checked still false
    assert checked == false;
  }

  if (!checker) {
    System.out.println("that is not a valid option");
  }
}
```